# Listen to RabbitMQ Queues at same time in different Virtual Host using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-amqp

I have multiple Clients each client has virtual host defined.

I need to provide ability to listen queues which are located in different virtual host.

SpringBoot , RabbitMQ I am using in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot can only auto configure one connection factory.

You will need to configure two or more sets of infrastructure beans (connection factory, container factory, template, etc).

You have to configure both because when Boot detects one, it disables its auto configuration.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableRabbit
public class So72953705Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72953705Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory fooConn() {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost", 5672);
        ccf.setVirtualHost("foo");
        return ccf;
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate fooTemplate(ConnectionFactory fooConn) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(fooConn);
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin fooAdmin(ConnectionFactory fooConn) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(fooConn);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory fooContFactory(ConnectionFactory fooConn) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(fooConn);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    ConnectionFactory barConn() {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost", 5672);
        ccf.setVirtualHost("bar");
        return ccf;
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitTemplate barTemplate(ConnectionFactory barConn) {
        return new RabbitTemplate(barConn);
    }

    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin barAdmin(ConnectionFactory barConn) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(barConn);
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory barContFactory(ConnectionFactory barConn) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(barConn);
        return factory;
    }

}

@Component
class FooListener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "fooQ", containerFactory = "fooContFactory")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}


@Component
class BarListener {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "barQ", containerFactory = "barContFactory")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

**EDIT2**

Dynamic registration of infrastructure beans.

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableRabbit
public class So72953705Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So72953705Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(DynamicRegistrar registrar) {
        return args -> {
            registrar.registerInfrastructure("foo");
            registrar.registerInfrastructure("bar");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class DynamicRegistrar {

    private final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    DynamicRegistrar(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    void registerInfrastructure(String virtualHost) {
        CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost", 5672);
        ccf.setVirtualHost(virtualHost);
        this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(virtualHost + ".cf", ccf);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(ccf, virtualHost + ".cf");

        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(ccf);
        this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(virtualHost + ".template", template);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(template, virtualHost + ".template");

        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(ccf);
        this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(virtualHost + ".admin", admin);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(admin, virtualHost + ".admin");

        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(ccf);
        container.setQueueNames("same.queue.name");
        container.setMessageListener(msg -> {
            System.out.println(msg + " from VH: " + msg.getMessageProperties().getHeader("fromVirtualHost"));
        });
        container.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(msg -> {
            msg.getMessageProperties().setHeader("fromVirtualHost", virtualHost);
            return msg;
        });
        this.beanFactory.registerSingleton(virtualHost + ".container", container);
        this.beanFactory.initializeBean(container, virtualHost + ".container");
        container.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey Garry !!  Thanks for prompt response. I would really appreciate if you could help me with some code references ?

Comment: I added an example; it uses Spring Boot, but the same technique applies to any Spring application.

Comment: Hey Garry !! thanks for the code reference. Only pain point here is let say we have few more clients eventually virtual host count will also increase. We need to add as many beans definition each and every time in the code when any new clients added. I was wondering if there is any possibility we can do it dynamically. Also looking for listening without using @ RabbitListener annotations otherwise I need to create as many listeners method . Hope you are able to understand.

Comment: Hey Garry !!   I saw your comment in of the blogs : Interesting - we don't currently support the same queue name on different virtual hosts - I will add a qualifier to support that - I will update the JIRA issue. – 
In my case all the queues in different virtual host has the same name. Is is supported now or Do we need to change queue name across different virtual host ?  Could you pls help me ?

Comment: In future, please make your requirements clearer from the outset to avoid wasting our time and yours. See the second edit. I am not sure what blog or JIRA you are referring to, but there is no limitation on using the same queue name on multiple virtual hosts (as can be see in the example).

Comment: Hey Garry !! I am very Sorry for that. Its my first post here. Its works for me edit 2 example.  One last question - Is there any possibility to know published message in queue belongs to which virtual host ?  Because in my case once I consume message from same queue(different vhost) if there is header present i.e reply-to = destinationQueue. I need to further send message to this destination queue but problem here is I don't know the vhost for it. Could you pls help me

Comment: You can add a `MessagePostProcessor` to the listener container to add a header - see the edit to my second edit (click on the `edited...` link to see just those changes.

Comment: Hey Garry !! Its working. Thanks for helping me out.