# Messages not being consumed by listener which is listening on default virtual host(/) after enabling dynamic support for multiple vhost

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Here is my configuration :

I am using Springboot RabbitMQ in my application.

There is one requirement I need to support listening vhost on one queue. After enabling this application stop working to consume messages in default vhost.

```
public class RabbitMqConfig implements RabbitListenerConfigurer {
@Bean
  public RabbitMessagingTemplate rabbitMessagingTemplate(
      RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate,
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitMessagingTemplate rabbitMessagingTemplate = new RabbitMessagingTemplate();
    SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory simpleRoutingConnectionFactory = new SimpleRoutingConnectionFactory();
    simpleRoutingConnectionFactory.setDefaultTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(simpleRoutingConnectionFactory);
    rabbitMessagingTemplate.setRabbitTemplate(rabbitTemplate);
    return rabbitMessagingTemplate;
  }

@Override
  public void configureRabbitListeners(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
    clients
        .stream()
        .forEach(client -> {
          var endpoint = createEndpoint(client.getVhost());
          var listenerContainerFactory = simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(client.getVhost());
          listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(
              annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getBean((client.getVhost()),
                  ConnectionFactory.class));
          registrar.registerEndpoint(endpoint, listenerContainerFactory);
        });
  }

public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory(String vHost) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
    CachingConnectionFactory cf = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    cf.setUsername(rabbitProperties.getUsername());
    cf.setPassword(rabbitProperties.getPassword());
    cf.setVirtualHost(vHost);
    cf.setHost(rabbitProperties.getHost());
    cf.setBeanName(vHost);
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(cf);
    annotationConfigWebApplicationContext.getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(vHost, cf);
    simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setContainerCustomizer(simpleMessageListenerContainer -> {
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.setQueueNames(graphqlMutationQueue);
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.setLookupKeyQualifier(graphqlMutationQueue);
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(msg -> {
        log.info(msg + " from VH: " + msg.getMessageProperties().getHeader(REPLY_TO_VHOST));
        updateGraphqlListener.onMessage(msg);
      });
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(msg -> {
        msg.getMessageProperties().setHeader(REPLY_TO_VHOST, vHost);
        return msg;
      });
      simpleMessageListenerContainer.start();
    });
    return simpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory;
  }

 private SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint createEndpoint(String vHost) {
    var endpoint = new SimpleRabbitListenerEndpoint();
    endpoint.setId(vHost);
    endpoint.setQueueNames(graphqlMutationQueue);
    endpoint.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    endpoint.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter("OnMessage"));
    return endpoint;
  }

}
```

At application startup time we are sending message to exchange :
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(graphQLExchangeName, StringUtils.EMPTY, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);

After this line execution messages are not being consumed by listener in default virtual host.

EDIT 2 :

```
@Bean
  RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory) {
    return new RabbitTemplate(defaultConnectionFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  RabbitAdmin rabbitAdminAdmin(ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory) {
    return new RabbitAdmin(defaultConnectionFactory);
  }

  @Bean
  SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory defaultContFactory(ConnectionFactory defaultConnectionFactory) {
    SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(defaultConnectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
  
  
  
  @RabbitListener(queues = "#{someQueue}", containerFactory = "defaultContFactory")
  public void onMessage(Map<?, ?> map) {
  
  }
  
  
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

Boot disables auto configuration whenever it detects user-defined infrastructure beans.

You need to manually configure the connection factory etc for the default vHost too.

Comment: Hey Gary ! Thanks for your reply. Do I also need to configure SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory bean for default virtual host  ?

Comment: Yes, but you will probably have to disable auto configuration altogether, as I showed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72953705/listen-to-rabbitmq-queues-at-same-time-in-different-virtual-host-using-springboo/72954289#72954289 - even if you are not using annotations - the annotation auto configuration fails when there are multiple connection factories.

Comment: I added defaultConnectionFactory , rabbit template(defaultConnectionFactory()) , rabbitadmin and SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory beans for default vhost.  Also modifed my listener class to use - @RabbitListener(queues = "#{someQueue}", containerFactory = "defaultContFactory") - seems its not working. I am suspecting messages were sent to default exchange by rabbitTemplate using other targetConnectionFactories than of default one. That's why listener was not able to consume messages.

Comment: Yes, you will need a template for each vHost. (In future, don't put code in comments,  it' hard to read; edit the question instead and comment that you have done so.

Comment: Hey Gary !! I have edit 2. Please see let me know what you think where its issue.

Comment: I can't guess; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and I will take a look at what's wrong.

Comment: DEBUG logging should help you figure it out.

Comment: Yaa , I will try now.